# Adding method to a method

Tags: javascript

I want my code to be like this:

```
select("*").where("you='me'").and("me='him'").and("game='nes'");
```

I have only this:

```
function select(selector){
    this.where = function(where){
        //Do something with where and select.
        //Add the method AND <---
    }
}
```

I dont know how to add the method add in the method where.

Comment: What it seems you are trying to achieve is calling `method chaining`, read a bit here: http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/simple-javascript-method-chaining/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called a 'fluent interface'

Simply `return this` from each function.

If you want to capture the "select" context, capture `this` in a variable within that scope and then return it when needed. This is important as `this` points at the function that is currently executing.

```
function select(s){

    var that = this;

    this.where = function(condition){
        that.filter(condition);
        return that; //this == select.where
    }

    this.and = function (condition) {
        that.filter(condition);
        return that;
    }

    this.end = function(){
        return that.results(); // or similar depending on the consumed api of course
    }

    return this; // this == select
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works! I will check you but I think there is a different method, like jQuery's, but thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In each function, put "return this;" at the bottom. So when you call .and() it's called on "this", which is "select". Sorry on iPhone, so no formatting!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it:

```
function select(selector){
    return {where:function(where){
        //do whatever you're doing with where and selector
        return {and:function(whatever){/*do something with whatever*/}}
    }}
}
```

you can add additional functions to each returned object

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/78aSa/1/

if you are trying to make it so that `and` and `where` are on the same object, do this instead:

```
function select(selector){
    var selectObj=this;
    this.where=function(where){
        //do whatever with where and select
        //now add the and method
        selectObj.and=function(whatever){
            //do stuff with selector, where, and whatever
        }
        return selectObj
    }
    return selectObj;
}
```

jsfiddle of this one: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/34BYa/